# Regular keyboard stuck as if a laptop function key was pressed

Tags: keyboard, fn-key

I have a regular PC keyboard plugged in a desktop PC with Windows 7

When I switched on the computer today I discovered that pressing <kbd>U</kbd> writes '4', <kbd>O</kbd> writes '5', <kbd>K</kbd> writes '2', etc. exactly as if you maintained down the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key of a laptop keyboard. This problem only happens if the num lock is switch on.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... that's just plain ol' numlock.  You would see the same result with numlock on and your external keyboard not attached.

Turn numlock off.

Comment: The problem is that this is not an external keyboard, I don't have a laptop but a desktop PC. And the "keep numlock turned off" solution doesn't really satisfy me :)

Comment: @Tomaka17 How can you say it doesn't satisfy you?? The problem is that it is using the letter keys as a number pad, when the Num Lock key is on (Which is a feature by the way, it's supposed to do that...). That is the only and proper way to turn it off. And if it is a desktop PC, how is it not an external keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I tried another keyboard, and this one is working correctly

I guess it was a problem with the hardware of the keyboard itself

Comment: Try that broken keyboard in another PC to see if it does the same thing as well, just to confirm it is the keyboard thats broken.

Answer (score 1):

Check the keyboard type in the property settings.  It may be configured as a laptop keyboard.